# Assembly language source formatter

Tags: assembly, code-formatting

It seems assembly language has gone somewhat out of fashion, and so with this I cannot find a beautifier/source formatting tool which might clean up quite the mess I've inherited.

Anyone have a suggestion on this?

Comment: Most commonly assembly language is in tabbed columns.  You just break the line at whitespace and put the first column (if any) hard left, the second (generally the main opcode) spaced over about 10, and anything else spaced over maybe 18 (depending on common opcode length).

Comment: Since assembly is usually line-oriented, writing such a tool from scratch doesn't sound like it would be all that hard.

Comment: I suggest that you learn some regex syntax and reformat the code according to your needs. Both Vim and Perl regex engines support very advanced features and either of them can be used for reformatting assembly code. I actually use Vim/Perl/awk regexes to reformat multiline MATLAB code blocks, for reformatting assembly quite basic regexes are probably sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `asm source beautifier`, there is a lot of them...
May be emacs could also help you with its numerous editing modes and `indent-region` macro...